# Python: Average of Non-Negative numbers

Tags: python-3.x, list, set, average, negative-number

```
def test(): # do not change this or the next line!
    numbers = [11.5, 28.3, 23.5, -4.8, 15.9, -63.1, 79.4, 80.0, 0, 67.4, -11.9, 32.6]
      average = 0

  # I need to write my code here so that it sets average
  # to the average of the non-negative numbers

     print(average)
  return average # do not change this line!
  # do not write any code below here  

    test()  # do not change this line!
# do not remove this line!
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to write my code so that it sets average to the average of the non-negative numbers.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. You must demonstrate your effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `numpy` .

STEPS:

- Find out the positive integers
- take a mean of those.

---

```
import numpy as np
def test(): # do not change this or the next line!
    numbers = [11.5, 28.3, 23.5, -4.8, 15.9, -63.1, 79.4, 80.0, 0, 67.4, -11.9, 32.6]
    num = np.array(numbers)
    avg = np.mean((num[num >= 0]), axis=0)
    return avg # do not change this line!
  # do not write any code below here  

test()
```

---

**Output:**

```
37.62222222222223
```

**Edit:**

```
def test(): # do not change this or the next line! 
    numbers = [11.5, 28.3, 23.5, -4.8, 15.9, -63.1, 79.4, 80.0, 0, 67.4, -11.9, 32.6] 
    num = [i for i in numbers if i>=0] 
    avg = sum(num)/len(num) 
    return avg # do not change this line! 
    # do not write any code below here   

test()
```

Comment: Where should I add that to the existing code? It says "np" is not defined. Please see https://snipboard.io/XBVgS0.jpg

Comment: do `import numpy as np`. The above is the complete code. You can add modify as per your requirement.

Comment: Sorry. This is for an online course and the platform does not allow modules like numpy. Would you mind providing a solution using the given code in my initial question?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. It is frown upon on SO to solve homework problems for someone who has not demonstrated any effort.

Comment: I do agree. That's why I also provided the steps. I hope it's for learning purposes not for just doing the assignment.

Comment: As I mentioned above, this is not a homework but for an online course I taking for computational thinking. :) Thanks for the help guys.